# How do you select languages when configuring mailman?

Tags: software-installation

I have ubuntu 10.04 installed on my VPS. I'm trying to install mailman. The problem I'm having is that once the installation starts it prompts asking me to select the languages that I'd like to use, but nothing that I do seems to actually select anything, pressing enter restarts the configuration wizard. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can go around that by doing it later but in the area where you can choose languages:

[image]

- <kbd>arrow up</kbd> or <kbd>arrow down</kbd>: navigate.
- <kbd>spacebar</kbd>: (de)activate choice.

Like so:

[image]

After you are done hit <kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>enter</kbd> to confirm the OK.

Comment: Thanks, I think I tried every other key except the spacebar. facepalm.

Comment: Hey! I was stumped by it too when I 1st tried tasksel ;) Happens to the best >:D

Comment: SPACEBAR! I too tried every other key before finding this post, couldn't they put that little nugget of info in the instructions above the list?

Comment: This way of selecting items is consistent with the way most web browsers treat [checkboxes](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_checkbox) and the way Nautilus and Windows Explorer treat multiple-selections (hold Ctrl). Enter is reserved for form submission or opening the selected files.